# Compare date read form file with input date

Tags: c, date

i'm having serious problems with a project in C language. I've created a function that takes in input some data about an entry in a sport center, but now i've to modify this function so that this function:

1. asks in input the last name who's entering
2. by last name inserted, it must go to the file of registrations, search and read the last date of registration for that last name.
3. Once found, save this date somewhere and compare it with the expiration date of membership for the member with that last name. If the entry date is less or equal to the expiration date, must allow the inserting of data, otherwise, terminate the program with a message like this: "Your membership has expired".

My difficulties are in the point 2 and 3 of this request. Can someone please help me, i'm in serious trouble

I post the basic code on which i've to do this:

```
void add_entry()
Date_entry de;
Entry e;
Entry eTemp;
FILE *fEnt; //file corso
FILE *fInd; //file indice del corso

printf("Number: ");
scanf("%d", &e.number);
printf("Name: ");
scanf("%s", &e.name);
printf("Surname: ");
scanf("%s", &e.surname);
printf("Date (DD/MM/YYYY): ");
scanf("%d/%d/%d", &de.day3, &de.month3, &de.year3);
printf("Entry time(HH:MM): ");
scanf("%s", &e.entry_time);
printf("Exit time(HH:MM): ");
scanf("%s", &e.exit_time);
e.deleted = 0;

int cont = 0;

fEnt = fopen(EntryOpen,"r+b");

fread(&eTemp,sizeof(Entry),1,fEnt);

while(eTemp.deleted != 1)
{
    fread(&eTemp,sizeof(Entrance),1,fEnt);
    cont++;
}

int posInEntry = cont;

fseek(fEnt,cont * sizeof(Entrance),0);
fwrite(&e,sizeof(Entrance),1,fEnt);
fclose(fEnt);

Index x;
Index xTemp;

strcpy(x.key,e.surname);
x.value = e.number;

fInd = fopen(indexOpen,"r+b");

cont = 0;
fread(&xTemp,sizeof(Index),1,fInd);

while(strcmp(xTemp.key,"EMPTY") != 0)
{
    fread(&xTemp,sizeof(Index),1,fInd);
    cont++;
}

fseek(fInd,cont * sizeof(Index),0);
fwrite(&x,sizeof(Index),1,fInd);
fclose(fInd);

IndexCode y;
IndexCode yTemp;

y.kye = e.number;
y.value = posInEntry;

fInd = fopen(indexCodeOpen,"r+b");

cont = 0;
fread(&yTemp,sizeof(IndexCode),1,fInd);

while(yTemp.key != -1)
{
    fread(&yTemp,sizeof(IndexCode),1,fInd);
    cont++;
}

fseek(fInd,cont * sizeof(IndexCode),0);
fwrite(&y,sizeof(IndexCode),1,fInd);
fclose(fInd);

IndexCode ind[max];
fInd = fopen(indexCodeOpen,"rb");

int i;
for(i = 0; i < max; i++)
{
    fread(&ind[i],sizeof(IndexCode),1,fInd);
}

fclose(fInd);

OrderIndexCode(ind,max);

fInd = fopen(indexCodeOpen,"wb");

for(i = 0; i < max; i++)
{
    fwrite(&ind[i],sizeof(IndexCode),1,fInd);
}
fclose(fInd);
printf("Index Update completed.\n");
```

Comment: Using `scanf` for user input is a bad idea. `scanf("%s", &...)` is a bug.

Comment: what should i use?

Comment: For user input? `fgets`, followed by `atoi` or `sscanf` if necessary (to convert the line to something else).

Comment: could you make me see an example?? so i can understand in concrete what you mean?

Comment: See, it's difficult to help you with input as long you do not show us the data input.

Comment: Should i publish the pic of in-execution program that shows data input?

Comment: Post the textual version of the input data, the result and the expected output.  (No pictures)  "My difficulties are in the point 2 and 3 of this request." is vague.  Please specify.

Comment: this program should do this ----> Insert last name: (e.g Rossi) -----> program goes to the file of gym membership and in it looks for the last name that has been inserted. Then, when found, program picks up expiration date for that member, saves it somewhere, and then compares it with entry date of that member. Now, if the entry date is less than expiration date, program allow this data insertion (that printf/scanf group). Otherwise, if entry date is greater than expiration date, program must print error message "Your membership has expired, renew it please. Goodbye" and program must terminate